# How to use exclusive BETWEEN clause in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, between

I have a php variable. I want check either it lies between values of two columns of any row of mysql table or not. But I do not want match that variable with exact values of table. i.e, exclusive BETWEEN clause. If anyone know answer then please explain with an example. Thank You. Here is my code.

```
$var = '15:00:00';


//Mysql Table (datatype of columns are TIME)

          first         last
row1      13:00:00      15:00:00
row2      17:00:00      19:00:00
```

Comment: Why can't you use `<` and `>` ?

Answer (score 11):

There is no "exclusive BETWEEN" operator in MySQL.

The expression:

```
  a BETWEEN b AND c
```

is really just shorthand, equivalent to this:

```
  ( a >= b AND a <= c )
```

If that's not the condition you want, you can use different comparison operators:

```
  ( a > b AND a < c )
```

---

If you want (need?) to achieve a result equivalent to that, but using the BETWEEN operator, you could use a bizarre combination of some conditions:

```
  ( a BETWEEN b AND c AND a NOT IN (b,c) )
```

Personally, I think the SQL is easier to understand if you avoid using `BETWEEN`.

---

There are several queries that can check whether a given value "matches" one or more rows in the table. For example:

```
  SELECT 1 AS `matched`
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.first < ?
     AND t.last  > ? 
    LIMIT 1
```

This query would return a row if there's a matching row, and return an empty set if there's not a matching row.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use expressions in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
where $var between `first` + INTERVAL 1 second AND `last` - INTERVAL 1 second
```

You can choose any intervals you need. And this even works with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `between` clause

```
  SELECT `column1`,`column1`,`column1` 
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE $var > `first` AND $var < `second`
```

something like this will only work if the value is in middle of something from first and second